# Why my Magento Cloud is returning 502?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento-cloud

I'm trying to build my new environment but I'm receiving error 502 every time. When I check the logs in the Magento Cloud panel I don't have the end of the file, it seems to be too long to show.

[image: Magento Cloud error 502]

Do you know how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the command `tail` to check the last lines of the files created by Magento Cloud.

```
magento-cloud ssh -e staging
tail var/log/cloud.log # if the error is in the setup:install or setup:upgrade
tail var/log/instal-upgrade.log
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento cloud will provide **http://URI/** or **https://URI/** like this.
and you are accessing the integration environment with **www.URI/**  if you access this with HTTP or HTTPS then it will work directly(without www).

If you want to access your web application using **www.URI/** then you need to add it in **routes.yaml** file.